# How to install only compiler and Debugger through msys2?

Tags: c++, gcc, gdb, c++20, msys2

I need updated GCC and GDB, as I have to learn c++(20) and practice some new features of it. But while installing I got a lot of things installed with msys2. Its quite hard to understand why msys2 needs this much space (refer image). Is there a specific command through which I can just install/get GCC and GDB. Any leads would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

**Reason of Request:** My HDD is just 500GB, so I have to think about space optimization and memory occupied by the programs.

**What I did:** Installed msys2 interface from [there official website](https://www.msys2.org/). After successful installation, I opened msys2.exe command line terminal from installation directory and used commands as follows:
Let me know if I've done something wrong.

1. pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc
2. pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gdb
3. pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-make

[image: Hard to understand why msys2 needs this much space]

Comment: Your commands are ok, and the resulting size is to be expected. 1.5G is not that much by modern standards. I suggest sucking it up, and cleaning the rest of your HDD with something like https://diskanalyzer.com/

Comment: I recommend using MSYS2 because it's great, but the MinGW-builds project provides a more minimal MinGW C/C++ toolchains you can download: https://www.mingw-w64.org/downloads/

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thank you for the suggestion, I'll surely look into it.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Yes you are right, internet is full of suggestions on MSYS2. But just want some info, have you ever tried Cygwin? And how much space it consumes? Any Idea? As I'm not doing any big projects, so that may be helpful.

Comment: Cygwin is a different beast, it includes POSIX emulation in the programs you compile. Unless you specifically want this feature, you should avoid it in favor of MSYS2.

Comment: Here's another decent MinGW distribution: https://winlibs.com/